# Parents of set in MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have a filter that selects a specific date in my date dimension,  This will be passed in as a parameter into the MDX query.

```
Filter([Date Dimension].[Calendar Year Hierarchy].[Actual Date].members,
        [Date Dimension].[Actual Date].CurrentMember.Properties( "Name" ) = '2011-09-01 00:00:00.000')
```

I would now like to select the weeks and/or months in the hierarchy above that.

[Date Dimension].[Calendar Year Hierarchy].[Month]
[Date Dimension].[Calendar Year Hierarchy].[Calendar Week]

I have tried several functions without much luck such as `.Parent` and `DrillupLevel`

I could be using them wrong or in the wrong spot,

thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

You could use the function GENERATE to get all ascendants:

```
Generate
 (
   {Filter([Date Dimension].[Calendar Year Hierarchy].[Actual Date].members,
        [Date Dimension].[Actual Date].CurrentMember.Properties( "Name" ) = 
'2011-09-01 00:00:00.000')},
{Ascendants([Date Dimension].[Calendar Year Hierarchy].CurrentMember)}
 )
```

Query using Adventure Works:

```
Select 
{[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]} On Columns,
{Generate(
{Filter([Date].[Calendar].[Date].members,[Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Properties("Name") = 'April 1, 2004')}, 
{Ascendants([Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember)})} On Rows
From    [Adventure Works]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the level you're looking for you can use [MDX Ancestor function](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Ancestor.html) instead of parent:

```
Ancestor([Date Dimension].[Calendar Year Hierarchy].currentmember, 
         [Date Dimension].[Calendar Year Hierarchy].[Month])
```

If no, it's fine using parent function. Note, using properties is not the quickest method to filter (for very large sets).

Why not using to [StrToMember MDX function](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/StrToMember.html) ?

```
StrToMember( ... here build your member with a string ... )
```

or if you can edit you mdx directly creating the statement directly with the help of a string builder ?

Answer (score 0):

so the answer i have at the moment is

> Filter([Date Dimension].[Calendar Year Hierarchy].[Actual
>   Date].members,        [Date Dimension].[Actual
>   Date].CurrentMember.Properties( "Name" ) = '2011-09-01 00:00:00.000')
>         .item(0).parent

using the `.item[0]` to get the item in the set
and the `.parent` to get that items parent (in my case i am actually calling it 3 times)

if anyone has any better ideas would love to here them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `STRTOSET` and for each input parameter replace `]` with `].Parent`, this way you will have set of parents.